# given $x$ irrational can you find $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a+bx = r$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

given $x$ irrational can you find $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a+bx = r$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm trying to solve this. My attempt consists of choosing $b$ close enough to $bx$ such that $bx \to 0$ and $a$ close enough to $r$ such that $a \to r$.

Or in a rigorous sense:

choose $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $bx = \epsilon$

choose $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a = r - \epsilon$

I can choose such $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ since $Q$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The title does not make sense. Given $x$, $a+bx$ is a fixed number for whatever $a,b$ one chooses. Do you mean that given $x$ irrational, and $r\in\mathbb{R}$, can one find $a,b\in{\mathbb Q}$ such that $a+bx=r$? Or you simply want to know if it is true that $\mathbb{R}=\{a+bx\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ for fixed irrational $x$?

Comment: You can't do it for all $r\in \Bbb R$, as there is no choice for $a, b$ which works simultaneously for $r = 2$ and at the same time for $r = 3$. For _any_ $r\in \Bbb R$, on the other hand, is a different question, and probably the one you meant to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you're asking if the simple field extension ${\Bbb Q}(x) = \{a+bx\mid a,b\in{\Bbb Q}\}$ can be equal to the real numbers? If so, note that the first set is denumerable, while the latter is not.

Answer (score 2):

That cannot work out for cardinality reasons, if $x$ is fixed. lets assume you would be able to do that, then this would mean that you would get a surjective map
$$\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R} \\ a , b \mapsto a+bx.$$
But the left set is countable, and the right one is uncountable, which produces a contradiction.